# Is this a faulty audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, deleted-answers, not-an-answer

Is this a faulty audit? (10K to see the answer) [Assigning an object to C++ array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67310170/13552470)

Image of the now-deleted answer:

[image]

Here is the body of the question:

[image]

The question is mainly asking

> "it won't affect the original object. Is that correct?"

And the now-deleted answer answered with

> Yes, it will not affect the 'original' object since your array consists of literal `Person` records, not pointers (`Person*`).

Did the answer even warrant deletion? I know the first line might be fluff, but still...

Here is the link to the audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28876303 I didn't review the audit, and I don't know how to directly link to one, so I linked another user's review *(status passed)*.

I also checked to see if the answer is a duplicate, and I've concluded that it's not, at least not completely.

Comment: My guess is that it may be a duplicate answer, but I could be wrong. Also, could you link the actual audit?

Comment: @10Rep Okay. And I've checked; it seems to bring something new to the table.

Comment: It was deleted through the low-quality review queue. To be honest, it seems that the first sentence deemed it a comment and got the majority of deletion votes. From here I'm only guessing that the simple fact that it got deleted from review made it an audit

Comment: Yeah, I guess some 2k reviewers got confused and recommended to delete the answer. Unless you have delete vote privileges you shouldn't delete answers that aren't strictly NAA.

Comment: @Tom yes that is true. For example code only answers cannot be deleted, etc. My point is that this audit was caused by reviewers who didn't know the correct way to review in the LQP.

Comment: @10Rep And I'm wrong with the Late Answer queue. The rules part is correct, but doesn't matter here, because the answer got deleted in a different queue. I read the history wrong :/

Comment: Wait this is about late-answers? That changes things :|

Comment: FWIW it was deleted via review from a LQP flag. I can't fault them too much, since it does read like a comment. Not a terribly good audit, tho. I mod deleted it so it won't show up as one anymore.

Comment: @Machavity Thanks! Should this post be marked as status-completed then? *(I know this wasn't tagged as bug)*

Comment: [Apparently a lot of users didn't like that answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28868442)

Comment: @AnnZen Nah. This was a specific incident and it's [discussion]. It will just fade back into the Meta

Comment: @Machavity Oh, okay.